# Get mp3 file frolm tableView select

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdictionary, avaudioplayer

I am trying to pull an mp3 file from a tableView row, when the user clicks on the tableViewCell i want that mp3 file to play on the detailView. But having trouble with the code. here is my code on the DetailViewController:

When I select the row I get a Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT" at the NSString *file line.Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    textLabel.text = lullabyLabelString;
    NSString *fileName = lullabyMP3String;


    NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName] ofType:NULL];


    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:file]error:&error];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [theAudio play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSBundle`'s `pathForResource: ofType:` expects an NSString and not a NSURL.

Try changing that line to:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil];
```

As you do not state it, I presume your file does in fact not have any file-extension. If it does, make sure you are providing one in that line above.